# Exporting rally project data

Tags: ruby, rally

Is it possible to export an entire project with all it's data from rally and how? Could it be done with the Ruby rally_api?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Project object in [Web Services API](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) does not have a attribute that references all data in it. There is no single object in WS API that can return the entire project if by entire project you mean all the artifacts in the project, iterations, releases, revision histories, etc. A single request will not do it. If you want to export artifacts, they normally have to be exported a type at a time. This can certainly be done with rally_api, but the limitations you encounter are not specific to the this ruby gem, but to WS API that does not provide a way to export all data related to a project.

Here is an example of moving a defect from one project to another within the same workspace. This will not work if the origin and designation projects are in different workspaces since Web Services requests are scoped to a workspace. You may comment out the query by formatted id if you want to include all defects in the project. I suggest testing the code on one artifact before moving all of them.

```
config = {:base_url => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm"}
config[:username] = "user@co.com"
config[:password] = "secret"
config[:workspace] = "W1"
config[:project] = "Top Project"
config[:version] = "v2.0"

    @rally = RallyAPI::RallyRestJson.new(config)
    query1 = RallyAPI::RallyQuery.new()
    query1.type = :project
    query1.fetch = "Name,ObjectID"
    query1.workspace = {"_ref" => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/12352608129.js" } 
    query1.query_string = "(Name = \"My Project 2\")"
    results1 = @rally.find(query1)
    project = results1.first
    puts project

    query2 = RallyAPI::RallyQuery.new()
    query2.type = :defect
    query2.fetch = "Name,FormattedID,Project"
    query2.workspace = {"_ref" => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/12352608129.js" }
    query2.query_string = "(FormattedID = DE74)"
    results2 = @rally.find(query2)
    results2.each do |d|
        d.read
        field_updates = {"Project" => project}
        d.update(field_updates)
        puts "Defect #{d["FormattedID"]} was moved to project: #{d["Project"]}"
    end
```

If you want to export artifacts out of Rally, e.g. to a csv file using rally_api that is also possible, but I do not have a working example of it.

Comment: And how would someone export, for example, all user stories? Is that possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. I updated the post with an example of moving a defect from one Rally project to another.